# if your base class has a virtual destructor, your own destructor is automatically virtual

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I know the title's statement is true.

What about a regular function?

For example

```
class Father {

    virtual void foo() {...;}

}

class Son : public Father {

    void foo() {...;}

}

class GrandSon : public Son {

    void foo() {...;}

}
```

Can GrandSon override Son's foo? In general, if your base class has a virtual function, the derived class's corresponding function is automatically virtual?
Is this true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing 'virtual' qualifier in function declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340437/missing-virtual-qualifier-in-function-declarations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in C++ a derived class "inherits" the virtual aspect of all methods--not just destructors.

Answer (score 4):

### C++ 2011: 10.3 Virtual Functions

2: If a virtual member function **vf** is declared in a class **Base** and in a class **Derived**, derived directly or indirectly from **Base**, a member function **vf** with the same name, parameter-type-list, cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as **Base::vf** is declared, then **Derived::vf** is also virtual (**whether or not it is so declared**) ...